# JPA -@Version for super class

Tags: jpa-2.0

I got super class AbstractEntity and all my entities classes (for example A , B ,C) inherited from it.

If I add:

```
  @Version
  @Column(name = "optlock", columnDefinition = "integer DEFAULT 0", nullable = false)
  private long version = 0L;
```

in my AbstractEntity  will this also work for classes A, B and C? Or maybe I need to add this annotation in each child class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work well for subclasses. It is a common pattern to put create an abstract entity class with id and version fields and extend it.